# What other languages allow programmers to use Interfaces as function parameters?

Tags: java, php, oop, design-patterns, interface

Let me explain:

I know that, **in Java**, you can do stuff like this:

```
int myMethod(Burnable obj){

 /*do stuff that's only applicable if the argument implements the Burnable 
  *interface
  */
}
```

I like programming in **PHP** the most, and I'm not sure **whether I can do that in PHP too**.

Furthermore, I'd like to know what other **reasonably mainstream** languages that feature this, as in my view it's a way of building **modularity** into your code.

Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: Ok you can overload this function for every class you want to use it with. But then you'd only see at runtime whether it actually applies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All statically-typed languages (C, C++, Java, Objective-C, Ada, and many others) allow one to specify the types of a function's parameters. A subset of them allow for overloading (having multiple different functions with the same name but with different typed parameters). Since PHP5, it is possible to specify the types of parameters using [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) to validate that function calls pass parameters of the expected type; however, PHP does not support overloading (although you can make functions accept multiple different types, and then check the types and dispatch to different implementations by type).

Comment: Does type-hinting in PHP5 include interfaces? I see no examples of this being used...

Comment: No, type hinting does not support interfaces. But if you don't care what the type is, only that it supports the methods you need, then you might as well just pass the parameter normally (and document the constraints on the parameter).

Comment: I guess you're right... I think you answered my question. That's a shame though... the fact that PHP doesn't support this...

Comment: Nice job getting at types, I think this may be what the OP was interested in.  This answer may be a bit dense for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

All the standard CLR languages (C#, VB.NET, F#) support using interfaces. Haskell has typeclasses which serve a similar function.

Comment: Yeah but if a language _supports_ interfaces it doesn't mean that it allows us to use it as an argument like I've written above.. Or does it?

Comment: @Felipe, I am not sure how a language could claim to support interfaces without providing this.  Functions are the bread-and-butter of programming.

Comment: @Felipe: What does it mean to "support" interfaces if they're not allowed as function arguments?

Comment: Well I think that a language could well allow us to define interfaces and implement those in our classes, at the same time not allowing Interfaces to define the _parameters_ or _arguments_ a function takes.

Comment: @Felipe: I can't imagine why you would be allowed to define and implement an interface that you couldn't then name as a function argument. It would be like allowing you to define a function but not let you call it.

Comment: Well if you follow the answer I selected as the right one, apparently 'tis what PHP does.

Comment: @Felipe: I see what you're saying. PHP is a dynamic language and doesn't have formal parameter types. It just has type hints that allows you to restrict parameters to object or array types (you can't even specify `int` or `string` as a hint). You can still use interfaces the same way you would use any other supported feature like `int` or `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Every object-oriented language allows this.  They differ in how they spell "interface".  In C++ it is just a particular kind of class, where every member is "pure virtual" (now known as "abstract").  In C# it's just like java.  In the dynamically-typed languages, PHP, Python, and Ruby for example, it is just implicit (i.e. the interface to which the argument must conform is not spelled out explicitly, but there still is an "interface" in the abstract).

The ability to do this is related to the Liskov substitution principle, and it is one of the fundamental tenets of object-oriented programming.  Glad you like it :-)

Comment: FYI, "pure virtual" and "abstract" are *NOT* the same; "pure virtual" means that there is no default implementation, whereas abstract means that there is a default implementation.

Comment: @Michael, I disagree.  For example, C# literally uses the word `abstract` to mean no default implementation -- must be overridden.

Comment: in the academic literature on types and type theory, abstract (in C++: virtual) is generally treated as distinct from interface (in C++: pure virtual). That's why Java, for example, clearly separates interface and abstract classes. Languages often trade off precision in terminology for brevity and uniformity. There are cases in C# where abstract actually does mean abstract, and I imagine that it would be fairly onerous to impose a different keyword for the other case.

Comment: @Michael, in the academic literature on type theory, abstract can also refer to the body of a lambda, a concrete thing whose implementation is not exposed, or the beginning section of a paper (jokes).  Anyway, academic literature is not the be-all-end-all of definitions, and neither is C#.  I have certainly used and heard `abstract` in my workplace to denote what it does above, so I stand by my usage.  Thank you for pointing out that there is contention.