# PHP Requiring specific type cohersion

Tags: php, casting

With the below code, $quantity is assumed to be an integer but I'm not doing any checking against it to require it to be so.

```
public function addProduct($product, $quantity) {
```

The below code will require it to be an integer, BUT if `$quantity = '1';` it'll fail because it's a string.  Is it possible for me to force `$quantity` to come through as an integer in this function, or do I HAVE to do `$object->addProduct($product, (int) $quantity);` ?

```
public function addProduct($product, int $quantity) {
```

Lastly, is it possible for me to flag $product as either a string or an integer, but if it's passed an object it'll break (without writing an `is_object()` check)

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP type-hinting to primitive values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724677/php-type-hinting-to-primitive-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type hinting is not available for primitive type. The only solution you have in this case is to use intval() or is_int() on your param :

```
public function addProduct($product, $quantity) {
 $quantity = intval($quantity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the type of an argument as either an Object or an Array, ie it cant be both -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that param gets in as an integer, simply add this line at the very begining of your method:

```
public function addProduct($product, $quantity) {
  $quantity = intval( $quantity );

  // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the value within the method itself

```
$quantity = (int) $quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cast the type to an integer. You should always cast to the appropriate data type for all your user-inputted values.

```
$quantity = (int) $quantity;
```

`$quantity` is now an integer