# is_numeric() vs. is_float() vs. is_int()

Tags: php, types, numbers

My understanding is...

if `is_numeric($input) === true`

then either

`is_float($input) === true` OR

`is_int($input) === true` OR

`$input === 0` OR

`$input` is a numeric string (meaning it'd satisfy one of the first 3 if it weren't wrapped in quotes).

Is that accurate? Are there other differences?

Comment: Read this table content : http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php maybe this is what you looking for..

Comment: I guess I was most confused about what floats are. I take it that anything that's a float is also numeric but not the opposite.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See PHP's documentation on [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php).  It talks about everything that is allowed, and it's more than `is_float` and `is_int`.

---

It's also important to note that `is_int` only works on things that are type integer, meaning string representations are not allowed.  This is a common problem when verifying that form input is an integer.  You should use `filter_var` or something from the filter family with the filter `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.  For floats, use `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT`.

---

Also, if the reason you are trying to check for an integer is to validate a parameter as being an int, then in PHP 7 you can do this:

```
function foo(int $i) {
    // $i is guaranteed to be an int (is_int) will be true
}
```

PHP 7 has two different modes for converting to int; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29205179/538216) explains it a bit more.

Note that this is probably not what you want if you are validating the contents of a form element. Use the `filter_var` solution for that.

Comment: you don't need a function, you can cast it to an integer: `$n = (int)$i`

Answer (score 3):

See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php). A numeric value can be:

- An integer
- A float
- Exponential
- A positive Hexadecimal
- A string containing most of these

Comment: Thx // Exponential notation is included in floats. You're right about hexes—it looks like they're not and there isn't a is_hex function.

Comment: @ryanve It is for PHP, but I wouldn't normally consider Exponential (scientific) a float.