# Stop giving error number_format for PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, error-handling, number-formatting

Here is question:

```
$var = 1000;
$var2 = number_format($var,2);// No error
```

And;

```
$var = 'Some String';
$var2 = number_format($var,2);// Gives 'number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double.... error'
```

My handling solution is;

```
$var = 'Some String';
$var_escape = 1000;
if(!$var2 = number_format($var,2)){
    $var2 = $var_escape;// if $var not a integer; always give 1000 to $var2.
}
```

This solution working perfectly but; still giving "*expect parameter error*"; because of this line:

> if(!$var2 = number_format($var,2)){

I don't want to use "**@**" supression. Is there any other solution for this issue? Thanks...

**MY INSPIRED BY ANSWERS SOLUTION**

```
if(!is_numeric($var2 = $var)){$var2 = $var_escape;}
```

Thanks all...

Comment: Check to see if the [string is a number](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) first?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307104/is-numeric-vs-is-float-vs-is-int/8307176

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if your input is a number or not using is_numeric function

```
$var = 'Some String';
$var_escape = 1000;
if(is_numeric($var))
$var2=number_format($var,2);
else
$var2=$var_escape;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just declare `$var2` in advance with the default value, then check to ensure that incoming value of `$var` is numeric using the built-in `is_numeric()` function in PHP. If the incoming value of `$var` is indeed numeric, assign that numeric value to `$var2`, else `$var2` will remain as the default `1000` as it's value.

```
$var2 = 1000;

if(is_numeric($var)){
  $var2 = number_format($var,2);
}

// You can proceed to use $var2 here as it will be 1000 or the value from $var if it was numeric.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex will be the easiest, this verifies that it's either an integer or a float.

> code

```
$vars = array(
    'Some String',
    123,
    123.5,
    -11,
    "123.55",
    "$2!!",
    .1,
    1,
    ".1",
    "1"
);

foreach($vars as $var) {

    if(0 !== preg_match('/^-?\d*\.?\d*$/', $var)) {
        echo number_format($var, 2) . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $var . " -> " . 1000 . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

> output

```
Some String -> 1000
123.00
123.50
-11.55
123.55
$2!! -> 1000
0.10
1.00
0.10
1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful... [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8bb067a52e36184cf42491ae94f20cd88724a892)

Use:

```
if(is_float($var) || is_integer($var)){
```

Instead of:

```
if(is_numeric($var)){
```

Unless you want your numeric strings to be processed as well.