# How to specify the type of the parameter in PHP

Tags: php, casting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP type-hinting to primitive values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724677/php-type-hinting-to-primitive-values)

Say, I create a function called

```
retrieveCount($count){
   return ++$count;
}
```

Just a simple example. How do I set the function to accept the type to be integers only?
in Java, or other languages, we have:

```
public int retrieveCount(int count){
   return ++count;
}
```

Is there a way do to the same thing in PHP? I read on the documentation that for OOP, PHP has type hinting for complex structures, such as objects, arrays, interfaces, etc, but no for scalar types (int, string).

Is this really the case, and we cannot specify the type?

Thank you

Comment: See: [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Comment: @JohnConde "Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string."

Comment: How do they type-hint the predefined functions then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no direct scalar type hint possibilities PHP. But you can emulate it by checking the type inside the function and trigger an appropriate error:

```
function retrieveCount( $count )
{
    if( !is_int( $count ) )
    {
        // I believe E_USER_WARNING is the appropriate error level
        // equivalent to what PHP issues itself on type hint errors
        trigger_error(
            'Argument 1 passed to retrieveCount() must be an integer',
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
    }

    return ++$count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this, however you can force the type within the function like so:

```
function retrieveCount($count) {
    $count = intval($count);
    return ++$count;
};
```

See similar functions `strval`, `floatval`...

Comment: But wouldn't that return 2, also raising a E_Notice but still, is it really a good way to solve the problem? That is, if you happen to pass an object...

Comment: Well, you could use `is_int()` and throw an error yourself if it's the wrong type.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the function receives an integer type, you'll want to call [is_int()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) like so:

```
function retriveCount( $count ){
  if( !is_int( $count ) )
    return 0; // or whatever you want errors to return

  return ++$count;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to be able to handle strings formed like numbers that aren't necessarily numbers, you could do the following:

```
function retriveCount( $count ){
  if( (int)$count != $count )
    return 0; // or err value

  return ++$count; // will be integer type
}
```

Read why return value will be an integer without any cast in [Type Juggling documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).