# Is it possible to instantiate a variable like 'String $a = 'abc';' in PHP?

Tags: php

All I ever see is

```
$var = "abc";
```

and I can't seem to find an answer

EDIT:
Sorry if the question is unclear.
I am aware that PHP uses mix types variables, but I wondered if it is possible to make a variable an explicit type.
As in:

```
String $var = 'abc'; // $var can only be of type String
$var = 5; // gives error
```

Comment: Why would you need type casting when the variable clearly is a string ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Comment: Have you tried it, or even done some research?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP type-hinting to primitive values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724677/php-type-hinting-to-primitive-values)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, and please don't write questions only in titles. It should be in the body.

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses mix type variables, a variable that can hold any kind of data, strings, integers, booleans, resources, etc..

If you want to typecast an `1` or `true` to a `boolean` you can do so with [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Or you can use [scalar type hinting](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints) available in PHP 7.