# String ..params not working on PHP 5

Tags: php, arrays, string

My code is here

```
<?php

        select("id","name");
        function select(string ...$value){
        var_dump($value);        
    }
```

But it's only working on php 7 . When I working on PHP 5.6 machine , I got fatal error like this.

```
Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to select() must be an instance of string, string given, called in [...][...] on line 2 and defined in [...][...]</b> on line 3
```

When I working on php 7 machine the output is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "id"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "name"
}
```

Doesn't php 5.6 support such kind of thing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you also posted the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use 'string', or any other primitive types, as typehints in PHP versions before 7.  See [PHP type-hinting to primitive values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724677/php-type-hinting-to-primitive-values).

You can just use the non-typehinted version if you need compatibility:

```
  <?php

        select("id","name");
        function select(...$value){
        var_dump($value);        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Badzen . I got it .